# vs2010 does not generate dll file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll

I'm trying to create a c++ dll in vs2010.
I've created a win32 project and selected "Dynamic Library" as configuration type.
I've added MyDll.cpp and MyDll.def.

This is mydll.h

```
#include "stdafx.h"

extern "C" BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

extern "C" UINT __stdcall stopGui(MSIHANDLE hModule) 
{
    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Stop Gui"), TEXT("Custom Action Monitor Machine"), MB_OK);
    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}

extern "C" UINT __stdcall stopService(MSIHANDLE hModule) 
{
    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Stop Service"), TEXT("Custom Action Monitor Machine"), MB_OK);
    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is MyDll.def

```
LIBRARY "MyDll"
DESCRIPTION "My library test"
EXPORTS
    ; Explicit exports can go here
    stopGui
    stopService
```

When I build the project I get "Build succeeded", but there isn't a dll file in my "release" directory. I just get a lot of log files with no errors and a couple of obj files.
How can I solve this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there one in the debug directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.
The output was in the "Debug" directory of the solution, while I was looking for it in the "Release" directory of the project.